# List the university having publications more than 800 in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame name cwurData related to university information and column name institution and publication I tried to code for List the university having publications more than 800 but it didn't work.

```
 cwurData[cwurData$publications >= 800(cwurData$pubication),'institution']
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `(cwurData$pubication)` after 800 in the code

```
cwurData[cwurData$publications >= 800,'institution']
```